# Making Google sheets for entries made today, this week, and this month

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a Google sheet that pulls information from a form.  The form inputs a timestamp and IDnumber into a spreadsheet.  I need to make different sheets to show which of these entries were made Today, This week, and This month.

Example

```
Timestamp       ID

12/1/2012       12345
12/1/2012       55555
12/4/2012       98765
12/15/2012      74823
```

I need to make a sheet that puts ID 12345 and 55555 into one "DAILY" Sheet, IDs 12345, 55555, and 98765 into a "WEEKLY" sheet, and one that has all of these in a "MONTHLY" sheet.

Comment: Honestly, hoping that there is enough similarity in the code that the massive excel community might be able to shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do...
Add today's date somewhere in the sheet (let's say cell D2) by inputting '=Today()' in D2.

In column C, next to your first two columns, add formulas to calculate the number of days between the date in column A and today's date. In row 2, the formula would look like this... 
=DATEDIF(A2,D2,"D")

Then, using the script editor in the spreadsheet, I would write a script that looks at column C and writes values from column A and B depending on that value. I haven't tested the script below, but I think it's what you would need. Essentially, it loops through column C of your results sheet. Depending on the value (days from today), that row is pushed to an array for each range. Then I cleared the sheet for that range before setting the values of the array. I hope this helps!

```js
function daysBetween(){
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
     formResultsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Results"),
     daySheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Today"),
     weekSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("This Week"),
     monthSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("This Month"),
     allData = formResultsSheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
     dayResults = [],
     weekResults = [],
     monthResults = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < formResultsSheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
      if (allData[i][2] === 0){
         dayResults.push(allData[i])
      } else if (allData[i][2] > 0 && allData[i][2] <= 7) {
         weekResults.push(allData[i])
      } else if (allData[i][2] > 7 && allData[i][2] <= 30) {
         monthResults.push(allData[i])
      }
    }
  daySheet.getDataRange().clear()
  daySheet.getRange(1,1,dayResults.length,dayResults[0].length).setValues(dayResults)
  weekSheet.getDataRange().clear()
  weekSheet.getRange(1,1,weekResults.length,weekResults[0].length).setValues(weekResults)
  monthSheet.getDataRange().clear()
  monthSheet.getRange(1,1,monthResults.length,monthResults[0].length).setValues(monthResults)
}
```